# Crooscompile qt5.4 for imx6

Tags: configuration, gstreamer, qt5.4

I am trying to crosscompile qt-everywhere-opensource-5.4.0 to iMx6 board.

The following is my configuration file (config.imx6):

```
./configure --prefix=/tools/rootfs/usr/local/qt-5.4.0 -examplesdir /tools/rootfs/usr/local/qt-5.4.0/examples -verbose -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -make examples -device imx6 \
    -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=\
    /home/acsia/Desktop/imx6-Qt5/arm-tool-chain/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi- \
    -no-pch -no-opengl -no-icu -no-xcb -no-c++11 \
    -opengl es2 \
    -eglfs \
    -compile-examples \
    -glib -gstreamer -pkg-config -no-directfb\
```

When I run `./config.imx` I am getting following error:

```
-gstreamer: invalid command-line switch
```

But same configuration file runs fine qt-everywhere-opensource-5.1.1

The platform I am using is ubuntu 14.04.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried Yocto?